# Unable Setting up a basic php contact form

Tags: php, html, contact-form

HI Appreciate any answers regarding this. I'm unable to get my php form to work even after double checking the variable over and again.

This is the form tag beginning -

```
<form name="sentMessage" action="contact.php" method="post" id="contactForm">
```

My PhP below -

```
<?php
$myemail  = 'nikhilnayak.in@gmail.com'; 

$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
$email = check_input($_POST['email'], "Enter your E-mail ID");
$phone = check_input($_POST['phone'], "Enter your Contact #");
$refemail = check_input($_POST['refemail']);


if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}
$subject = 'New Website Lead' ;

$headers = "From: $name";

$message = "
Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Contact #: $phone

References:
$refemail
" ;

mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $headers);

header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit();

function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>

[HTML BODY HERE}

<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Please guys, any help is useful. This has been uploaded and its not working even when live...

This is the HTML form -

```
<form name="sentMessage" action="contact.php" method="post" id="contactForm">
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div>
                                <label style="margin-right:85px; font-size:16px;">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div>
                                <label style="margin-right:20px; font-size:16px;">Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div>
                                <label style="margin-right:15px; font-size:16px;">Phone Number</label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number (+974)" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
           <p>If you would like to refer someone else or if you have multiple e-mail IDs, enter them below</p>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div>
                                <label style="margin-right:40px; font-size:16px;">References</label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Email 1; Email 2; Email 3" id="refemail" required data-validation-required-message="Please the E-mail IDs.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <br>
                        <div id="success"></div>
                        <div class="row" style="display:inline-block; text-align:center;">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

UPDATE ----

HI GUYS, thanks for your answers... removed the re-validation in the PHP and it seems to re-direct to the thank you page...
but the email i get is blank (without the $name, $phone, etc...)

new PHP code -

```
$name = check_input($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = check_input($_REQUEST['email']);
$phone = check_input($_REQUEST['phone']);
$refemail = check_input($_REQUEST['refemail']);
```

and i have removed the below code.

```
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
    }
```

UPDATE

Answered by linil

Comment: you're exiting before executing  any of the below exit function

Comment: paste your form html and what error you are facing?

Comment: not showing any error, it loads URL contact.php and displays the HTML within, which is the contact.html page instead of the thankyou.html page. Thats why I know it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine.

You should first try wrapping the `mail()` and the following `exit()` statements in a condition. As it is now, you are attempting to mail and exiting before the HTML get loaded for the client to fill in contact information.

See below:

Your New HTML

```
<form name="sentMessage" action="contact.php" method="post" id="contactForm">
  <div class="row control-group">
    <div>
      <label style="margin-right:85px; font-size:16px;">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row control-group">
    <div>
      <label style="margin-right:20px; font-size:16px;">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" name="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row control-group">
    <div>
      <label style="margin-right:15px; font-size:16px;">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number (+974)" id="phone" name="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p>If you would like to refer someone else or if you have multiple e-mail IDs, enter them below</p>
  <div class="row control-group">
    <div>
      <label style="margin-right:40px; font-size:16px;">References</label>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Email 1; Email 2; Email 3" id="refemail" name="refemail" required data-validation-required-message="Please the E-mail IDs.">
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="success"></div>
  <div class="row" style="display:inline-block; text-align:center;">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Your new PHP

```
<?php
  $myemail = 'nikhilnayak.in@gmail.com';

  $name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
  $email = check_input($_POST['email'], "Enter your E-mail ID");
  $phone = check_input($_POST['phone'], "Enter your Contact #");
  $refemail = check_input($_POST['refemail']);

  if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
  {
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
  }
  $subject = 'New Website Lead';

  $headers = "From: $name";

  $message = "
Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Contact #: $phone

References:
$refemail
";
  if ($name && $email)
  { //add a condition that validates the email for sending

    mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $headers);
    header('Location: thankyou.html');
    exit();
  }

  function check_input($data, $problem = '')
  {
    echo $data;
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
      show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
  }

  function show_error($myError)
  {
    ?>

    [HTML BODY HERE}

    <?php
    exit();
  }
?>
```

Hope that helps.

UPDATE:

try replacing your `$header` with this:

```
$headers = "From: $name <nobody@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">";
```

Also, replace the following so we can see why you may be getting blank mails:

```
if ($name && $email)
  { //add a condition that validates the email for sending
    print_r($message); exit; 
    /* 
         if Name, Email, Contact and References are not set. 
         It mean their name value are not still set in your HTML code
         Note: while print_r is in effect. this page won't redirect. 
         we are debugging. 
         Remove the print_r line after you start getting expected values
         and redirect will work fine.
    */
    mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $headers);
    header('Location: thankyou.html');
    exit();
  }
```

Comment: nope, didn't work... same result... loads contact.php in browser not thank you page

Comment: @masmrdrr could you please let me know, is the mail getting sent? you didn't add name tags in you input fields. pls see new edit

Comment: fixed the code, (edited in my question), page redirects to thankyou.html, but getting blank email (see updated question - last part)

Comment: @masmrdrr Put this `print_r($message); exit;` before your `mail()` and let me know what you see

Comment: it prints **Name: E-mail: Contact #: References:** on the browser window and no email. does not redirect to thankyou.html

Comment: @masmrdrr if it prints it out exactly like that, then you may still have their name values unset in you HTML code. Could you please copy the HTML code I rewrote for you and try that and let me know?

Comment: Thanks a ton mate, I found the issue....

the issue was in the <input> I had not defined the "name=" attribute. Was confused that the id="name" would sort the task...

THANKS A TON!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$myemail  = 'nikhilnayak.in@gmail.com'; 
if(isset($_POST['name'] && $_POST['email'] && $_POST['phone'] && $_POST['refemail']){
      $name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
      $email = check_input($_POST['email'], "Enter your E-mail ID");
      $phone = check_input($_POST['phone'], "Enter your Contact #");
      $refemail = check_input($_POST['refemail']);

    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
    }
    $subject = 'New Website Lead' ;

    $headers = "From: $name";

    $message = "
    Name: $name
    E-mail: $email
    Contact #: $phone

    References:
    $refemail
    " ;

    mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $headers);

    header('Location: thankyou.html');
    exit();
}


function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{    
 //try to echo the html here instead
}
```